# compiling dependencies with processor sub architecture: x86-64-v3, x86-64-v4 (AVX512)

Tags: x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture, conan

I'm using conan on a linux x86_64 platform and I would like my dependencies to sometimes be compiled with target architecture x86-64-v4 (where we have target hosts with AVX-512) or x86-64-v3 (where only AVX2 is available). In the end, this means adding the compiler option -march=xxx. Different binaries signatures are needed.

I've seen the section on customizing the settings. I'm using the CMAKE Toolchain generator. (But happy to consider any solution that would work.)

For my own packages it's easy because I can check the setting in my recipe. But for the dependencies any ideas?

Cheers, Thanks.

Comment: You will need to build all them from sources again. And, you will need to set your global configuration to add "-march" to tools.build:cflags and tools.build:cxxflags

More info: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/config_files/global_conf.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing out where I could add options. However this does not seem to be incorporated in a package signature. I updated my profile to specify these options and the still wanted to use all the versions in my cache despite their build being for the wrong arch.

Comment: Indeed those configuration are not part of the package ID, only the architecture. In that case, you would need to change it directly in the recipe. As real example: https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/973af3d6c6eadd55686f14de4bcf891465473d5f/recipes/nasm/all/conanfile.py#L61